# Separate Lists in Separate Columns

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Word, I'm trying to create a numbered list in one column of a table, and a separate one in the other. However, when I put "a" in the top row (both columns), the next row (both columns) will auto-format to have "b" and "c", when I just want "b" in both cells. Is there a way to do this, or will I just have to make do with this limitation?

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you show what your table looks like?  Why do you even want "a" followed by "b" if you want a *numbered* list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably happening is that both of your entries in the second row are inheriting their numbering from the first column. If they're the same paragraph style, Word treats them all as part of the same list unless you choose to restart at a. (which doesn't get what you want either.)

If you want the numbers (or letters) in column 1 and the list in column 2 to update independently of each other, you need to define two separate list styles and associate them with two different paragraph styles.

1. On the Home Tab, in the Styles area, click the small arrow to expand
   the Styles menu.
2. Click the **New Style** button to create a new style. Name it
   whatever makes sense for the document you're working on. I'm going
   to assume in these directions that your two list styles are "Column 
   1 List" and "Column 2 List."
3. Click **New Style** again and perform the same process to create
   "Column 2 List" (or whatever you want to call it). Next to **Style
   based on:**, select Normal or no style instead of Column 1 List, to
   keep it from auto-updating from Column 1.
4. On the Home Tab, select the **Multilevel list** icon.
5. Select **Define New List Style**.
6. Name your new list style (for example, List 1).
7. Select **Format** then **Numbering**
8. Select **More** in the lower left corner.
9. Under **Link level to style**, select Column 1 List. (Make sure
   you're at level 1.)
10. Format the numbering however you want it to appear in your
     document.
11. Click **OK.**
12. Repeat the **Define New List Style** process, making List 2 and
     linking level 1 to your Column 2 List style.
13. Select column 1 and assign it the Column 1 List paragraph style.
14. Do the same for column 2 with the Column 2 list style.

This will get you two completely separate lists, which means that if you add cells to one column and not the other, you'll have different numbers in the same row.